# Multiple File Upload Widgets on the same page - main.js

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I am trying to change main.js for blueimp upload files to have multiple file upload widgets on the same page. I changed id to class for form. I also changed in main.js:

```
$('.fileupload').each(function () {
    $(this).fileupload({
        dropZone: $(this)
        url: 'server/php/'
    });
});

$('.fileupload').each(function () {
    $(this).fileupload({
        dropZone: $(this)
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
        /\/[^\/]*$/,
        '/cors/result.html?%s'
    )
   });
});
```

still not working. Any idea? Thanks a lot. katarina

Comment: Look at the JavaScript console and see what errors you're receiving.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console

Comment: I checked it and I found 0 errors there :-(

Comment: 09:55:17.378 "Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id." all.js:56
09:55:17.383 "The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating" all.js:56
09:55:17.402 "FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()."

Comment: @wikinka sorry I'm not able to figure out your problem. Just confirm whether that plugin requires `id` of your `div`. go through its documentation.

Comment: Thank you james I'll try different way how to do it. have a nice day. k

Answer (score 0):

on the page where you create the two instance of upload widget you should give the action parameter to your forms.

```html
<form class="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<form class="fileupload" action="server/php2/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In the main.js you should use this attribute of your form to call the different upload handlers:

```html
$('.fileupload').each(function () {
 var action = $(this).attr('action');
 
    $(this).fileupload({
  dropZone: $(this),
  url: action,
 });
});
```